# Call render again at the top level and maintain mutability

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this test below that ensures that the component is pure (is using the `PureRenderMixin`) and I'm getting the following warning.

> Warning: setProps(...) and replaceProps(...) are deprecated. Instead, call render again at the top level.

```
  it('renders as a pure component', () => {
    const pair = ['Trainspotting', '28 Days Later'];
    const component = renderIntoDocument(
      <Voting pair={pair} />
    );

    let firstButton = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'button')[0];
    expect(firstButton.textContent).to.equal('Trainspotting');

    pair[0] = 'Sunshine';
    component.setProps({pair: pair});
    firstButton = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'button')[0];
    expect(firstButton.textContent).to.equal('Trainspotting');
  });
```

However I can't re-render the entire component without maintaining mutability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about creating a different/new component for the second test?

```
it('renders as a pure component', () => {
  const pair = ['Trainspotting', '28 Days Later'];
  const component = renderIntoDocument(
    <Voting pair={pair} />
  );

  let firstButton = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component,   'button')[0];
  expect(firstButton.textContent).to.equal('Trainspotting');

  pair[0] = 'Sunshine';
  const component2 = renderIntoDocument(
    <Voting pair={pair} />
  );
  firstButton = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component2, 'button')[0];
  expect(firstButton.textContent).to.equal('Trainspotting');
});
```